# How to dynamically update projected nodes?

Tags: angular

I have a simple scenario where I want to dynamically render components with content projection.

Basically I have two simple components:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'A',
  template: '<h1>A</h1><p><ng-content></ng-content></p>'
})
export class AComponent {}
```

and

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'B',
  template: '<h1>B</h1><p><ng-content></ng-content></p>'
})
export class BComponent {}
```

Now I want to dynamically decide which of them to render in a given situation depending on another parameter. For this I create a structural directive C:

```js
@Directive({
  selector: 'C'
})
export class CDirective implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  C! : string;

  constructor(private vcRef: ViewContainerRef, private tRef: TemplateRef<unknown>){}

  ngOnInit() {
    const contentView = this.templateRef.createEmbeddedView(null);
    contentView.detectChanges();
    
    if (C === 'A') {
       this.vcRef.createComponent<AComponent>(AComponent, {projectableNodes: [contentView.rootNodes]}); 
    } else {
       this.vcRef.createComponent<BComponent>(BComponent, {projectableNodes: [contentView.rootNodes]}); 
    }
  }
}
```

An I use it like this:

```html
<ng-container *C="'A'">The content</ng-container>
```

This works well as long as the content is static. It does not work anymore if I change the content of my container dynamically like this:

```html
<ng-container *C="'A'">A counter: {{count}}</ng-container>
```

Changes in the `count` parameter are not reflected in the rendered template. Is there any way to dynamically update the content of projected roots?

Here is an example in stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hkqspj?file=src/app/c.directive.ts (backported to Angular 12)